# How do I connect my smart contract to my local test network?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ganache, decentralized-applications

I'm attempting to go through this [20 min Dapp Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkZ6iYnSDRw).

I update the HTML file to include the contract ABI and contract address, then go to Remix to deploy my contract on my ganache test node.

[image]

Once ganache is up and running I select the web 3 provider in the drop down of the deploy interface in remix and it prompts me with this.

[image]

I edit the local IP to match my ganache which is 7545, but once I do this it just changes back to injected web 3 and now I can't select any of my truffle addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Metamask (browser extension) [Metamask extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en) and add your Ganache IP and port there (and the accounts you want to use), and then use injected web3 in remix.

Also, you could use your local IP (the one that most likely starts with 192.168.), instead of localhost (127.0.0.1) when setting up the Ganache server. You can change this in Ganache by pressing the settings wheel on the right, then select 'Server' and select from the dropdown under Hostname the desired IP.